# Disable multiple logic apps across different Resource Groups

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell

I have a use case where I want to disable the old Logic Apps that our company is no longer using. All the Logic App are present in different environments and needs to disabled from all, ex: dev, sit, uat, prod. Rather than going to different RGs and disabling them one by one I am trying to develop a script which takes the portion of the Logic App name and disables it across all the resource group.

I was following this article but it shows how to disable multiple logic apps under one resource group and not what I am trying to achieve. [https://www.integration-playbook.io/docs/properly-disable-logic-apps-in-powershell][1]

I tried making some changes in the script to solve my use case but not sure how to test it and make necessary adjustments. I am very new to Logic Apps and would appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

I have added the displayName parameter so that that particular logic app is disabled and not all under the resource group. But I am not sure how to move forward.

```
# This script disables or enables all Logic apps under given resource group
# ./DisableEnable-LogicApps.ps1 "FC-CUS-DEV-INT-RG" "Disabled"
# Parameters are resourceGroupName and Disabled | Enabled


param([string] $displayName, [string] $state)

function ChangeLogicAppState([string] $logicAppName, [string] $resourceGroupName, [string] $desiredState, [string] $displayName)
{
    Write-Host 'Checking logic app ' $logicAppName

    $logicApp = Get-AzLogicApp -displayName $displayName -Name $logicAppName
    Write-Host ($logicApp | Format-List | Out-String)
        
    $apiOperation = 'unknown'
    if($desiredState -eq 'Enabled')
    {
        $apiOperation = 'enable'    
    }
    elseif($desiredState -eq 'Disabled')
    {
        $apiOperation = 'disable'
    }
        
    if($logicApp -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Host 'Logic App does not exist: ' $logicAppName
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host 'Logic App does exist: ' $logicAppName

        $currentState = $logicApp.State.ToLower()        
        if($currentState -eq $desiredState.ToLower())
        {
            Write-Host 'Logic App ' $logicApp.Name ' is already in the desired state'
            $script:Unchanged++
        }
        else
        {
            $url = 'https://management.azure.com/' + $logicApp.Id + '/' + $apiOperation + '?api-version=2016-06-01'
            $response = az rest --method post --uri $url 
            $script:Changed++
            Write-Host 'Logic App Changed'

            $logicApp = Get-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $logicAppName
            Write-Host ($logicApp | Format-List | Out-String)
        } 
                       
    }
}



Write-Host '================================='
Write-Host 'Starting the script to: ' $state
Write-Host '*********************************'

#Declare variables
$Total = 0
$Changed = 0
$Unchanged = 0

#Get each logic app in loop
Write-Host 'Looping logic apps in Resource Group: ' $resourcegroupName
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Logic/workflows" -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroupName | ForEach-Object {
ChangeLogicAppState -logicAppName $_.Name -desiredState $state  -resourceGroupName $resourcegroupName
$Total++

}

Write-Host 'Summary:'
Write-Host '#################################'
Write-Host 'Total:' $Total ' Changed:' $Changed  ' Unchanged:' $Unchanged
Write-Host '#################################'

Write-Host '*********************************'
Write-Host 'Ending the script.'
Write-Host '================================='
```

Comment: Do you *need* to do this via an Azure Function?

Comment: I am very new to Azure functions and Logic Apps in general. The ask is to come up with a script that can be run in CLI or PowerShell so that the Logic Apps can be disabled without doing that manually one by one. Is there any other way to achieve this efficiently? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can enable/disable it from the Azure portal as shown below,
[image]

Comment: Note that this is not the Resource Group but the Logic Apps view :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so most of the `function` within your script is redundant since the functionality is already present within `Set-AzLogicApp` already.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.logicapp/set-azlogicapp?view=azps-7.5.0#syntax

Below is the basic usage of `Set-AzLogicApp`

```
Set-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $logicAppName -State Disabled
```

#### Get-AzLogicApp Name Filtering

Unfortunately `Get-AzLogicApp` doesn't allow you to filter for all logic apps by a particular name as it requires you to pass the mandatory resourceGroup and Name parameters.

What you can do though is utilise `Get-AzResource` cmdlet which does allow wildcard search of resources.

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows' -ResourceName testlog*
```

You can then use the output to disable the logic apps based on a displayName filter.

The below script has been simplified from the example you were looking at earlier by using the cmdlets from the `Az.LogicApp` module

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$displayName,
    
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateSet('Enabled', 'Disabled')]
    [string]$State
)

# This will return all logic apps that start with the name testlog*
$logicApp = Get-AzResource -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows' -ResourceName $displayName*

# Loop through all returned logic apps and set the state
foreach ($app in $logicApp) {
    'Attempting to update state of: {0}' -f $app.Name
    Set-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName $app.ResourceGroupName -Name $app.Name -State $State -Force
}
```

I would normally have just used the pipeline and done something like

```
$logicApp | Set-AzLogicApp -State Disabled
```

However this doesn't appear to work on the latest version of the module as `Name` parameter does not take pipeline input.

I raised an issue on the Azure PowerShell repo to see if that could be fixed in a future release:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/18053